# Finding Nodes in list by properties on C#

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of node and each node has this properties:

```
List
    node 1  {EquivalenceNo: 9, EquivalenceSing: -};
    node 2  {EquivalenceNo: 8, EquivalenceSing: -};
    node 3  {EquivalenceNo: 9, EquivalenceSing: +};
    node 4  {EquivalenceNo: 7, EquivalenceSing: +};
    node 4  {EquivalenceNo: 7, EquivalenceSing: +};
```

I'd like to select only the nodes which has the same EquivalenceNo and the opposite EquivalenceSing and getting another list  like this:

```
 List
        node 1  {EquivalenceNo: 9, EquivalenceSing: -};
        node 2  {EquivalenceNo: 9, EquivalenceSing: +};
```

I implemented this expression which returned all the occurrence:

```
  listLeft.GroupBy(x => x.EquivalenceNo )
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .SelectMany(y => y)
          .ToList()
```

but only worked with smalls list which had only one occurrence. But since i'm treating with long lists which have a lot of nodes and there would be more than one occurrence not regarding what i need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this linq statement (i think, it was my answer on your another question :)) you don't filter out nodes with differenet Sign, you just take all with more than one occirance of the same number. I would propose to count signs in the group and take only groups with more than 1 sign. Something like:

```
var res = listLeft.GroupBy(x => x.EquivalenceNo)
                  .Where(g => 
                     g.Select(t=>t.EquivalenceSing).Distinct().Count()>1 )
                  .SelectMany(y => y)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: it didn't work :( ; don't know why. I think its because in your expression you're handling the equivalence sing as integers an this properties is a char on my nodes. Then; i tried this  `listLeft.GroupBy(x => x.EquivalenceNo).Where(g =>g.Select(t => t.EquivalenceSign == '-' && t.EquivalenceSign == '-').Distinct().Count() > 1).SelectMany(y => y).ToList();`  but also didn't work. any suggestion?

Comment: @superkiller170793  yes, give us  that example, where it doesn't  work. Your example from the question works with my code and with a code from Lukasz Makowej  . Try to explain more detailed what thex expected output is.

Comment: I alredy gave you my expample where it didn't work. beacuse I'm traying to find those nodes which has the same equivalence number and the opposite sign.Moreover, the propery is Char,  as you said in the second comments ,  `Distinc`t  would work if the property were either enum or string

Comment: @superkiller170793  Distinct works fine with char too. In your example nodes with same number and  opposite sign are node 1 and node 3  with EquivalenceNo 9 and signs - and +  (not node2, it has EquivalenceNo 8). My code gives exact that result.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin you were totally rigth, I was implementing the code in a wrong way. I was using other property of my node which also handles signs but the property that should have been, really sorry for this misunderstanding.